# In chrome dev tools what is the combination of these attributes called and why can i not just do a quick copy of them

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I don't see anything in the right-click menu that will give me this.  I always have to write it manually

[image]

Comment: I read it several time but couldn't understand. What exactly are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about `button#checkout.button-1.checkout-button`? If so, I'm not aware of a way to copy-paste this, or a name for it, but it is constructed with the format

```
htmlTag#idOfElement.class.with.periods.instead.of.spaces
```

It is pretty commonly a unique selector for the element in question.